# Remove all styles of DOM in child layout

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code to show a dialog.

```
$("#duplicateDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "OK": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#duplicateDialog").dialog("open");
```

The problem is the parent layout already changed the button's styles.

```
button {
    height: 22px!important;
    padding: 0 2px!important;   
}
```

Now I'd like to remove the "height" and "padding" above in child layout. How to do it?

Note: The child layout `extends` from another layout which includes the above button style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a class for your dialog buttons guess above jquery 1.8+

```
    ....
  buttons:{
               "cancel" : {

                "class": 'myClass', 
                click: function() {
}
...
```

Comment: It works! I defined a class with important height and padding and apply for it.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that will override those styles, if they are present, is inline styling that also has !important. so, `<button style="height: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"></button>`.

You can find where they are being added by jQuery, probably with append() or prepend(). And add your inline styles there, so something like:

```
$('.parent').append('<div class="yourSituation" style="border: 0; padding: 0;"></div>');
```

Comment: But the dialog's buttons are generated by JQuery. How to set "style" attribute for them?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another option... [Apprise](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-v2-The-new-and-improved-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery) allows for a custom css class - **className** - on the buttons.